# Drawing OCX to given printer-devicecontext

Tags: visual-c++, printing, mfc, drawing, ocx

In order to print some data I have to print an OCX as well. To do so I create a printer-dc from the GUI, print on it and so on. When it comes to printing the OCX I want to use its existing Draw-Method but to the printer-devicecontext I have. 
The code shown seems to work but look kind of hacked to me and I'm not sure if it works just "by accident". 
So the question is: Is this the right way to give a device-Context via Com-call to the OCX and use it?

This is in an Visual-C++-MFC-Project targeting windows

```
///////////////////////////////////// OCX
//IDL
[id(79)] void DrawBeamerToDC(OLE_HANDLE printerDC,
                             LONG drawRectLeft, LONG drawRectTop,
                             LONG drawRectRight, LONG drawRectBottom);
```

```cpp
//the OCX-.cpp
void CSPCListViewCtrl::DrawBeamerToDC(OLE_HANDLE printerDC,
                                      LONG drawRectLeft, LONG drawRectTop,
                                      LONG drawRectRight, LONG drawRectBottom)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

    CRect rectDraw(drawRectLeft, drawRectTop, drawRectRight, drawRectBottom);
    CDC* pDc = CDC::FromHandle((HDC)printerDC);
    DrawMe(pDc, rectDraw);
}
```

```cpp
////////////////////////////////// client
//the OCX-Wrapper (generated)
//note that OLE_HANDLE  gets translated to a plain long
void CSPCListView::DrawBeamerToDC(long printerDC,
                                  long drawRectLeft, long drawRectTop,
                                  long drawRectRight, long drawRectBottom)
{
    static BYTE parms[] = VTS_I4 VTS_I4 VTS_I4 VTS_I4 VTS_I4;
    InvokeHelper(0x4f, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms,
                 printerDC,
                 drawRectLeft, drawRectTop,
                 drawRectRight, drawRectBottom);
}
```

```cpp
//the callers .cpp
CRect rectBeamer = GetRectoPrintInColumnRectFromPrintRect();
CSPCListView* ptestctrl = GetOCXToPrint();
ptestctrl->DrawBeamerToDC((long)m_hPrintDC,
                          rectBeamer.left, rectBeamer.top,
                          rectBeamer.right, rectBeamer.bottom);
```

Comment: This looks pretty much ok. The OCX provides a device-agnostic rendering implementation, allowing client code to pass any given device context to it. The only issue is with the device context: An `HDC` is pointer sized, so the code can fail in a 64-bit build. In a 32-bit build, the code works by accident, but it is an accident you can rely on (a pointer is 32 bits, so is a `long`; sign extension isn't an issue either).

Comment: thank you. maybe casting to `OLE_HANDLE` or using `HandleToLong` would be better (clearer, safer for future) than just the `long`-cast?